# Why does this explicit cast not work when there is an implicit conversion defined?

Tags: c#, casting

I have a class with a defined implicit conversion to int:

```
public class SpeakerId
{
   private int value;
   public SpeakerId(int value) 
   { 
     this.value = value;
   }

   //integer conversions
   public static implicit operator SpeakerId(int value) => new SpeakerId(value);
   public static implicit operator int(SpeakerId obj) => obj.value;

   ...
}
```

With those conversions operators, I would think that this code would work:

```
var value = new SpeakerId(3);
var speakerId = (int)value;
```

but it doesn't; it causes a `Specified cast is not valid` error. Why would that be?

**Update**:
My original code sample does work. The place where I get the error is when there's an intermediate cast to object, as you would have in a value converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
  var speakerId = (int)value;
            
  return ...
}
```

or, easier to see:

```
  var value = new SpeakerId(3);
  object intermediate = value;
  var speakerId = (int)intermediate;
```

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IvIDdH)

Comment: No repro. With this code even `int speakerId = value;` would work

Comment: Agreed, the actual scenario is when there's an intermediate cast. I updated my post to give the example.

Comment: It doesn't work because you are losing compile-time type information.

Comment: @OndrejTucny: why does that matter? The error is at run time. Can't the compiler check the type of the object at run time and also that there is a defined conversion operator?

Comment: Because type conversions are resolved at compile-time, not run-time, except for `dynamic` types. See this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#explicit-dynamic-conversions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So `(int)` against an `object` is unboxing, not casting, and doesn't invoke any conversion operators<sup>1</sup>. You need to cast your object back to your reference type before you can try applying `(int)` to act as an actual cast:

```
var speakerId = (int)(SpeakerId)value;
```

Or you need to ensure you cast to `int` before it gets converted to `object` so that it *is* a boxed `int` and can be unboxed.

---

Alternatively, if you don't know what the type of `value` is going to be but you're "sure" it'll have an appropriate conversion operator defined, you can force the lookup for a conversion to happen at runtime via `dynamic`:

```
var speakerId = (int)(dynamic)value;
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Except for some oddities around enums and their base types, unboxing has to be *exactly* to the type that was originally boxed.

Comment: Why can't the runtime check that the value is of type `SpeakerId` and that there is a defined conversion operator?

Comment: @JoshuaFrank - because the runtime isn't responsible for inserting conversions. The compiler is and, at that point (ignoring the boxing/unboxing issues) the only types in consideration are `int` and `object`, neither of which contains any such operators.

Comment: @JoshuaFrank - you *could* insert a `(dynamic)` cast instead of the specific `(SenderId)` cast if you do want to start up all of the compiler machinery to inspect *runtime* types and potentially find a better conversion.